# How to add system property equivalent to java -D in Ant

Tags: java, ant, build-process, build

I need to set *java -Djava.library.path=/some/path* and I want to do it when I am running my ant script, building my jar.

I think I have to use

```
<sysproperty key="java.library.path" value="/some/path"/>
```

but it doesnt work. I cannot make the syntax work. The only thing I have Googled and found is sysproperty in conjunction with

```
 <java classname>
```

but that doesnt make any sense to me.

I am not sure if this is relevant, but I am using ant to create a ear and deploying this ear in JBoss.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here is an example Ant target `run` that executes the `example.jar` and passes a system property with `key="java.library.path"` and `value="/some/path"`:

```
<target name="run">
    <java jar="example.jar" fork="true">
        <jvmarg value="-Djava.library.path=/some/path"/>
    </java>
</target>
```

Comment: Although I haven't tested this, I hope its right, so I will accept this instead

Answer (score 2):

did you try to run

```
ant -Djava.library.path=/some/path ...  ?
```

Comment: No I haven't tried this. But I am running ant inside eclipse. Not sure how I can add that parameter in eclipse.

Comment: I would much rather avoid doing it like that if I have a choice

Comment: Ok, I tried what you suggested, and it still didn't work.
I still get don't get the value I added when I print out System.getProperty("java.library.path"). Just much other things.

Comment: what put those "much other things" there? normally this is not set.

Comment: I don't know. I'm guessing JBoss.
The value I have now is: 
    11:44:55,656 INFO  [OpenOfficeService] java.library.path is: /usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.5.0_22/jre/lib/i386/server:/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.5.0_22/jre/lib/i386:/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.5.0_22/jre/../lib/i386:/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun-1.6.0.15/jre/lib/i386/client:/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun-1.6.0.15/jre/lib/i386:/usr/lib/xulrunner-addons:/usr/lib/xulrunner-addons

However, I would like to add /usr/lib/ure/lib

Comment: if you figure out who sets this value, you will have a chance to configure it to set something else.

how exactly are you running ant?

Answer (score -2):

I found out how I can solve this.

Seems like since we are using ant to create and deploy our application in a Application Server (Web Server), in our case JBoss, we had to modify

```
run.sh
```

and add the java.library.path as a VM argument there.

Something like this:

```
JBOSS_NATIVE_DIR="$JBOSS_NATIVE_DIR:/usr/lib/ure/lib/"
JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Djava.library.path=$JBOSS_NATIVE_DIR"
```

**Thus, it is not correct to pass in VM arguments in ant.**

Comment: that does not really answer the general question of how to pass system properties with ant...