# passing java.library.path parameter to testng

Tags: java, testng

How can I pass java.library.path to TestNG?

I need to do the equivalent of

```
java -Djava.library.path=/blah
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are bootstrapping a web server, you can write it in the run configuration script in the web server.

For instance in JBoss look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2378357/how-to-add-system-property-equivalent-to-java-d-in-ant/2432280#2432280).

Comment: No - I am trying to run a test which has some JNI dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

You use the jvmarg ant tag like

`<jvmarg value="-Djava.library.path=${basedir}\lib" />`

Answer (score -1):

This is a system property that's interpreted by the JVM, why would TestNG care about it?

Comment: Because testng starts the JVM, not I.

Comment: Er... no. TestNG is running in the same JVM you are running your tests, it doesn't launch any JVM. Are you referring to the TestNG Eclipse plug-in, by any chance?

Comment: You don't answer a question by asking a question. Please rephrase your answer.